# Change canvas color on touch

Tags: android, canvas, touch

I'm playing with android coding and I have created a canvas that use all the screen size and I need some help to add a touch event in this canvas for every time that someone touches it the canvas change the color.

EDIT 2

I managed to insert a click event in my layout, but i didn't work very well, its only managed to paint the first time.

```
public class Modetwo_paint extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_paint);
        ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);         

        ll.setOnClickListener(this);                    
        drawView = new DrawViewSingle(this ,width, height, a[0], r[0], g[0], b[0]); //a, r, g, b, they are arrays of int
        ll.addView(drawView);                

}

 public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String s;
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.layout_paint:
            clicks+=1;
            if (clicks >= a.length) {
                clicks = 0;
            }
            s = "Teste " + clicks;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            drawView = new DrawViewSingle(this ,width, height, a[clicks], r[clicks], g[clicks], b[clicks]);
            ll.addView(drawView);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

My DrawViewSingle Class

```
public class DrawViewSingle extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int x;
    int y;
    int a;
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    int size;


    public DrawViewSingle(Context context, int x, int y,  int a , int r, int g, int b) {
        super(context);         
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.a = a;
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {        
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);        
        paint.setARGB(a, r, g, b);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, x, y, paint ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that you have

Comment: Without any code, I am unsure as to what you are trying to accomplish, maybe this will help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: Hey guys, i add some code to my question, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

So, my friend  told me to change the LinearLayout background once my canvas use the screen size. Now i don´t need the drawview class anymore

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.layout_paint:
            clicks+=1;
            if (clicks >= a.length) {
                clicks = 0;
            }       
            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(a[clicks], r[clicks], g[clicks], b[clicks]));

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```